# Retrieving element with no name or id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some code to accomplish something very simple.  I have never worked with a PayPal button before, which is causing some difficulty.

I have been able to simulate a button click before, using document.getElementById or document.getElementsByName(), however, the form I am trying to submit above does not have a name, or an id, so I do not know how to refer to it in my code.

I am trying to write a short chrome extension using Javascript that will find the paypal form/button on the page (that I do not own or have control over), and submit it without me having to click it.  Any guidance/links would be much appreciated.

Comment: be more specific. Is this your HTML? If so, get rid of those tables, they have no reason to exist. Also, if it's your HTML you can introduce ids or a name or a class. If not, how did this end up in a document that you have JavaScript execution power on?

Comment: Mike, thanks for responding.  I did not write the code above.  The code exists on a page that I have no control over.  I am trying to write a chrome extension using that can find this form, and submit it without me clicking the button.  Since the form has no name or id, I do not know how to refer to it in the code that I write.

Comment: please update your post with that information.

Comment: Clarified in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your button has a name, so you can use [.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

```
var btn = document.getElementsByname('submit')[0]
```

If you have access to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or you can add [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to your project then

```
var btn = jQuery('input[name="submit"]')
```

Comment: Nice catch Arun! If you go this route, make sure there aren't any other forms on this page.  That's a common button name for submit buttons, and sign in/register forms are common on pages where paypal forms are present.

Comment: This worked very well:

    document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].click();

Comment: Thank you very much guys.  Should have asked before I spent a day trying to figure this out on my own :D

Answer (score 0):

This would be MUCH easier with jQuery, but with native js, you could do:

```
function getPaypalForms()
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < allForms.length; i++)
  {
    if (allForms[i].getAttribute('action') == 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr')
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingElements;
}
```

There are many ways to edit this function above to suit your purposes even better.  You could edit it to collect just the submit buttons from these forms, or refactor it to accept a string to match an attr, and value.  However, like I said, this would be much easier using jquery:

```
$('form[action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, first off: don't do this, unless you're trying to swindle people out of money. In which case, don't do this =) (I'm not a lawyer, but I'm pretty sure paypal can go "well you didn't click the button, you automated it. And now someone's site made you spend $500 that you didn't want to. tough"). That said: document.getElementsByTagName("form"), then filter on getAttribute("action").

Comment: 1: Paypal sees the request, not how the user chose to launch it. (paypal won't know you automated it, and there api even provides services to do just that.) 2: The navigating user has to physically sign in to their account, so it's not just going to suck money from people. 3.  your 'answer' was identical to mine... w/out the code.  Why did you not just leave it as a comment?

Comment: because I posted it pretty much at the same time, presumably. When I hit reply, there was no answer yet.